# Conditional Gaussian Process With scalar mean

Tags: statistics, bayesian

For any multivariate Gaussian distribution which has 
$$
\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m},\mathbf{S})
$$
we have 
$$
\mathbf{m}_{a|b} = \mathbf{m}_a+\mathbf{S}_{ab}\mathbf{S}_{bb}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_b-\mathbf{m}_b)
$$
If $\mathbf{m} = m\overrightarrow{1}$, i.e., $\mathbf{m} = [m,m,...,m]^{T}$, do we have
$$
\mathbf{m}_{a|b} = \mathbf{S}_{ab}\mathbf{S}_{bb}^{-1}\mathbf{x}_b?
$$
For $m=0$, it is right. But I have no idea about the case $m \neq 0$.

This question is from the paper [variational inference for gaussian process modulated poisson processes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0254) (see Equation 5 and helpful description above it). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why would you not have $(1-\mathbf{S}_{ab}\mathbf{S}_{bb}^{-1})m +\mathbf{S}_{ab}\mathbf{S}_{bb}^{-1}\mathbf{x}_b$?

Comment: @Henry I think my question is a bit unclear.Your solution is correct but the paper I mentioned got a simpler solution. I do not know how they made it.